# How to render a view when a webhook is received?

Tags: express, ejs, webhooks

I have an iframe which embeds a Zoho Form in my HTML code. When I click the submit button, I receive a webhook from Zoho which contains a payload. How can I render a new page to display the values received from the webhook? The code below is how I handle the webhook when it arrives.

```
app.post("/hook", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).end();
});
```

Comment: You will need to store the relevant data on the server side, and then make a new request from the client to fetch and display it there.

Comment: @CBroe thank you for the response, I stored the payload in a variable and I used the "Acknowledgement & Redirects" functionality from Zoho Forms to redirect the page to the one I wanted.